# Add border to button when clicked

Tags: javascript, loops, dom-events, onclicklistener, addeventlistener

I have four buttons, I would like that each time one of them is clicked it has a blue border. And if another one is clicked, the previous one will immediately get back its usual border style.

I tried with loop but it doesn't work

Comment: Suggestion: can you post a minimal example of what you tried or what you'd like to start from?

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use CSS `:focus` to give it the blue border.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus